# Looking for a modern payment processor which accepts adult sites

Tags: ecommerce, payments, payment-gateway, creditcard, adult-content

I love how easy authorize.net is to use, but they don't accept adult sites. I am lanching an adult site soon but I can't find any good credit card processors I can use. Most sites use CCbill or Epoch but they are both terrible since the customer is redirected to their external site which also has an ancient 1990's look. It's not like authorize.net's API that you can query and get the result back as to whether the payment went through or not. This makes authorize.net blend seamlessly with the product. But since adult sites are against their TOS and also paypals, what is a good alternative?

I am looking for one that won't redirect the user from my site, is big enough to be reliable and trustworthy and has fairly low rates.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You know CCBill is the most popular their payment pages may look out dated but why not use their API and create your own pages. http://www.ccbill.com/developers/api.php

Comment: CCBill's interface is horrible. I've heard plenty problems with them shaving sales too.

Comment: @neak you know I said CCBill has an API, and if you feel they are shaving sales whatever that is you can always contact them and your attorney. They've been in business this long for a reason. Otherwise run some searches in Google for adult merchant accounts or simply high risk merchant accounts pickup a phone and call the companies to ask do you accept adult websites.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, depending on how much you expect to earn from this site, would be to get a merchant account of your own, and process the payments yourself. This is not going to be as easy as you are looking for though.